# How to find the best value for mean and STD of Normalize in torchvision.transforms

Tags: python, pytorch

I have started working with PyTorch and cannot figure it how I am supposed to find mean and std as the input parameters of normalise.

I have seen this

```
transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)) #https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#
```

and in another example:

```
transformation = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5,0.5,0.5],std=[0.5,0.5,0.5])
])  #https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/ml-basics/blob/master/challenges/05%20%20-%20Safari%20CNN%20Solution%20(PyTorch).ipynb
```

so, how am I supposed to know or get these values if I have a set of images?
Are these three parameters are related to R G B also?

Comment: I think the first ones are based on imagenet dataset. Either way, for me the mean and std used for imagenet related tasks usually work well if the domain is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have already X_train which is a list of numpy matrix eg. 32x32x3:

```
X_train = X_train / 255 #normalization of pixels
train_mean = X_train.reshape(3,-1).mean(axis=1)
train_std = X_train.reshape(3,-1).std(axis=1)
```

then you can pass this last 2 variables in your normalizer transformer :

```
transforms.Normalize(mean = train_mean ,std = train_std)
```

Comment: Hi, if you think is the right answer then please add a +1 by clicking on the arrow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment, you can use ImageNet statistics for general domains. Otherwise, you can use this from PyTorch forms [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-normalization-using-pre-trained-vgg16-networks/23560/6) to calculate mean and std for your own dataset which needs to be normalised.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = torch.randn(100, 3, 24, 24)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        return x

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    

dataset = MyDataset()
loader = DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=10,
    num_workers=1,
    shuffle=False
)


mean = 0.
std = 0.
nb_samples = 0.
for data in loader:
    batch_samples = data.size(0)
    data = data.view(batch_samples, data.size(1), -1)
    mean += data.mean(2).sum(0)
    std += data.std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the answer, first, I do not think std is additive, second,  this would give the mean of the actual data which needs to be normalised? unless you normalize the data first, which has not been mentioned in the answer! can you plz explain more, what is the Dataset object here, cannot run the code

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you were looking for a way to calculate the mean and std of your own dataset. Then you can use torchvision transforms to normalize your data. Pass in the mean and std as calculated above.

Comment: Although std is not additive, this gives a reasonably accurate estimate which is good enough for this purpose. For more info, check out the link I have provided. If your dataset is small enough to fit in the RAM, this can be done directly instead. Then you will get the exact std.

Comment: Thanks, I am reading that link, at the bottom, there are some other suggestions that I am trying to figure out. To be fair, you asked a good question, I am not sure that std and mean should be calculated based on the actual data or normalized data but it makes more sense if it is based on the actual data (my misunderstanding, thanks)

Comment: Glad it helped! If you find anything else that's important, feel free to add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, keeps you updated in the next few days

Comment: thx southmith 4 the earlier support, I am trying to run the above code, but cannot figure out how to run it successfully? I replaced "class MyDataset(Dataset)" with "class MyDataset()" , but getting "DataLoader worker (pid(s) 22320) exited unexpectedly" , however, how can I use the above code on a folder of images, it would be great if someone can post the code which runs on a specifc folder of images

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html